# What are all the ways to count to 10 in Scala?

Tags: scala, iteration, range

We can count to 10 in Java with a couple of different syntax variations:

```
public class IterationDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

In Scala we can start at least one version with something similar:

```
for (i <- 1 to 10) {
    println(i)
}
```

My question is: **What are all the ways to count to 10 in Scala?**

Comment: Questions on [so] should have a *clear* problem statement and a *single* objectively correct answer. You have not explained what the *precise* programming problem is that you are solving, i.e. how is not knowing the answer to this question currently preventing you from writing your program? Note that questions asking for list of things are off-topic, and questions without a clear problem statement are off-topic. In particular, I believe there is a trivial proof that there are infinitely many ways to count to 10 in Scala, which is the *exact opposite* of a single answer.

Comment: This isn't a useful question because that number is obviously infinite in pretty much any programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using a for-loop expression**

syntax:

> for (x <- expr) body

```
for ( i <- 1 to 10) println(i)
for ( i <- 1.to(10)) println(i)
for ( i <- 1 until 10+1) println(i)
for ( i <- 1.until(10+1)) println(i)
for ( i <- Range(1,10+1)) println(i)
for ( i <- List.range(1,10+1)) println(i)
for ( i <- List.tabulate(10)(_ + 1)) println(i)
```

**Everything you use in a for loop syntax can also be expressed in terms of foreach**

syntax:

> expr foreach (x => body)

```
(1 to 10).foreach(println)
(1.to(10)).foreach(println)
(1 until 10+1).foreach(println)
(1.until(10+1)).foreach(println)
Range(1,10+1).foreach(println)
List.range(1,10+1).foreach(println)
List.tabulate(10)(_ + 1).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are five different ways, however, there may be more.

In addition, the methods that use `List` (`List.range` and `List.tabulate`) can also be substituted with other types with the same interface. For example `Vector.tabulate`.

```scala
(1 to 10).foreach(println)
(1 until 11).foreach(println)
Range(1, 11).foreach(println)
List.range(1, 11).foreach(println)
List.tabulate(10)(_ + 1).foreach(println)
```